# Website show me "It works" page sometimes when access from external network

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, dns, request

I have a strange problem. I have a website, running on an **Ubuntu 16.04** server, with **Apache 2.4.18**. In the beginning of the developer, I can only access the site in the Local Network, from my computer. I edit my **hosts file** to access:

> < Local Server Ip > < Website Url >

For example:

> 192.168.1.30 test.website.com

And I could access the site without problem. But now, the site needs to be visible from outside our LAN, in other words, from internet. So, the guys from Networks add our public IP and the Domain DNS and the subdomain of the site. This is where the problem is.

Sometimes, when I try to access the site from outside, from my cellphone or in my house, the site is displayed correctly, without problem (with some styles problem, but that is other theme). But, sometimes, I think 7 of 10 times, the site is not displayed, and shows me the Apache ***"It Works!"*** page instead. Local, I still see the site correctly, but from external, the problem persists.

I tested in the server, checking the **access_log** of the site. I see that when the site is displayed correctly, in the log is printed the http request:

> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200

But, when it throws at me the ***"It Works!"*** page, the log does not show me anything.

So, I have two theories:

1) Sometimes, the requests is sent to other server.

2) Sometimes, the requests reach my server, but with other request different to my site (for example, other url), If it is possible in any way.

Does someone know how can I verify and fix this? Some recommendations or guide for what could be happening?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

From your comments:

**@alanlittle:** I don´t have a general access log, how can I enable it? (To be honest, I did not know that I could). About **mod_rewrite**, well, it is displayed in the **Loaded Modules** entries of phpinfo(), Is it could be cause of something?

**@Ray O'Donnell:** Here is my virtualhost example of the cofiguration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/inetpub/test.website.com

    ServerName test.website.com
    ServerAdmin eliacim.davila@xxxxxxx.xxx

    ErrorLog "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-error.log"
    CustomLog "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/inetpub/test.website.com>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
#       Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**@Jeff Puckett II:** We don´t have a load balancer (As Far As I Know). I run the **nslookup** command, and it show me this:

```
Server: b.resolvers.Level13.net
Address: 4.2.2.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: test.website.com
Address: 189.219.xx.xxx (NOTE: Our Public IP)
```

Comment: Interesting. Well, if it's not accessing the site, then the access logs for the site of course wouldn't show anything. Do you have a general access log configured? Are you using mod_rewrite anywhere?

Comment: Can you show your `VirtualHost` configuration?

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in play? Is DNS round-robin in effect? From a terminal, run `nslookup your.example.com` and see how many records are returned.

Comment: In your httpd.conf file, look for `<IfModule log_config_module>` and you'll see some various directives. Look for the CustomLog directive. You'll see the comments there say `If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost> container, they will be logged here` Enable that if it's not, and it should log any requests which don't go to your <VirtualHost> log.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your `VirtualHost` config. I'd be inclined to agree with @JeffPuckettII's line of thought - something is interfering with the request reaching your server.